# jQuery selector to find inputs inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML like this:

```
<div class="s-item s-question">
    <label>label text</label>
    <div>
        <input name="s1" type="checkbox" class="switch-indeterminate k-input"
               data-indeterminate="true"
               data-on-text="Yes"
               data-off-text="No" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Dynamically with jQuery, how can I select that input? I want to determine when a change occurs.

The highest level div will always have class `s-item` but instead of a checkbox, sometimes I might have a button or a select box, etc.

So I thought maybe `$('.s-item').find('select, input, button').change(function() { ... });` would work? But it didn't.

What should I do?

Comment: It works here - http://jsfiddle.net/hvvdp9ox/

Comment: `$('.s-item').find(':input')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "change" event is only valid on `input`, `select`, and `textarea` elements. It doesn't work because you are attempting to assign it to a `button` element.

```
$('.s-item').find('select, input, textarea').change(function() { ... });
```

should work.

It would be cleaner simply to assign a class to the items you care about, so you could just do

```
$(".s-change-watch").change(function() { ... });
```

which better separates the semantics of markup (like what element type it is) from functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following to get the checkbox then check the value

```
$('.s-item div input')
```

or just give the input an id or class and select that.